# In a finite unichain average-reward MDP, how does optimal bias vector depend on stage reward

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning

Consider a finite unichain MDP with stage reward $r$, state space $S=\{1, \dots, n\}$, action space A, and transition probability $p$. The Bellman equation is
$$ h(i) + g= \max_{a \in A} ( r(i,a ) + \sum_{j\in S} p_{ij}(a) h(j)$$
Under the finite unichain assumption, and requiring $h(n)=0$,  there exists a unique solution $(g_r, h_r)$.

Now, under the same transition probability, there is another reward function $v$. We can solve the Bellman equation plus $h(n)=0$ under stage reward $v$, and find a unique solution $(g_v, h_v)$.

My question is, does the following claim hold?

Claim: there exists a constant $\kappa$ that does not depend on $r$ or $v$, but may depend on transition probabilities and $n$, such that
$$ \max_{i\in S} | h_r(i)-h_v(i)| \leq \kappa \max_{i\in S, a\in A} | r(i,a)- v(i,a)|$$.

I can prove the claim when the MDP is recurrent, or when there is a special state that is always recurrent under all policies. But I fail to prove it for general unichain MDP.

In fact, I highly doubt if this claim is correct in general unichain models, but am having a hard time constructing a counterexample.

It would be great if someone has some ideas on the proof, or the construction of a counterexample.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Where does $\kappa$ appear in the subsequent formula?

Comment: Sorry it is a typo. It should be $$ \max_i | h_r(i)-h_v(i)|<= \kappa \max_{i,a} | r(i,a)-v(i,a)|$$